# Hello i am beginner in coding, In google app script I have 2forms and want to post trucks data in a same sheet and same row. with Same Truck number

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a Data Entry Truck System and in this system I have two forms and One Sheet which is used to store data. ONE form is used for the port and the other is used for the Yard. Which means that a person at port is the first to fill data and when a Truck have arrive at the yard a person at the yard fill data also, But the data Filled at the Yard must be inserted in the same row that have a same truck details from the port. So as to complete the truck transportation details.**

The problem is that it only allow me to enter in data in a blank row force me to the blank row Ineed help in this how to set any row but which contain a data with a "getRange(blankRow,17)" But what I am in a need is the row to allow me post in same row that that have a same Truck Number.

```
if (validateEntry()==true)
{

var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,12).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("D8").getValue()); 

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,13).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("D10").getValue()); 

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,14).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("D16").getValue()); 

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,15).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("D18").getValue());

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,16).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("D20").getValue());

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,17).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("H8").getValue());

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,18).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("H10").getValue());

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,21).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("H16").getValue());

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,22).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("H18").getValue());

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,23).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("H20").getValue());

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,19).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("L8").getValue());

datasheet.getRange(blankRow,20).setValue(shSutForm.getRange("L10").getValue());

ui.alert('TRUCK DATA SAVED');

shSutForm.getRange("D8").clear();
shSutForm.getRange("D10").clear();
shSutForm.getRange("D16").clear();
shSutForm.getRange("D18").clear();
shSutForm.getRange("D20").clear();

shSutForm.getRange("H8").clear();
shSutForm.getRange("H10").clear();
shSutForm.getRange("H16").clear();
shSutForm.getRange("H18").clear();
shSutForm.getRange("H20").clear();

shSutForm.getRange("L8").clear();
shSutForm.getRange("L10").clear();

} 


}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And don't SHOUT (write in all upper case) at us. It's rather rude to shout at the people you ask for help.

Comment: First I would advise not using the Form Response sheet as a calculation sheet.  Use it simply to record form responses.  Have another sheet to collect and manipulate the data.  You can use onFormSubmit() trigger to copy the response to another sheet for processing and truck lookup.

Comment: I could use some sheet images

Comment: Thank you @TheWizEd God bless you let me now try this solution

Comment: Thank you @Someprogrammerdude and i am sorry i did not know that.

Comment: Thank you @Cooper but system tell me i did not have permission to post picture yet

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this sort of technique

```
//Allow each form to have a separate linked sheet.  Just leave the linked sheets alone to store data
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const dsh = e.source.getSheet("DataSheet");
  if(sh.getName() == "PortSheetName") {
    //fill in the DataSheet from port sheet form data and include drivers name or truck number  

  }else if(sh.getName() == "YardSheetName") {
    //fill in the DataSheet from yard sheet form data and use drivers name or truck number to find the proper row
  }

}
```